# Converting from mysql to mysqli and getting Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli as array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, compiler-errors

I am working on converting some PHP code from mysql to mysqli. I have created an error and am unable to understand how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The code looks like this:

```
    <?php
include ("admin/includes/connect.php");

$query = "select * from posts order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,5";

$run = mysqli_query($conn["___mysqli_ston"], $query);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$title = $row['post_title'];
$image = $row['post_image'];

?>
```

The error produced is: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli as array
The error is being called out on this line:

$run = mysqli_query($conn["___mysqli_ston"], $query);

In the line above $conn is a variable from the database connect file which has this code:

```
<?php

// Stored the db login credentials in separate file.
require("db_info.php");

// Supressing automated warnings which could give out clues to database user name, etc.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Try to open a connection to a MySQL server and catch any failure with a controlled error message.
try {

$conn=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password) or die ("$dberror1");

} catch (Exception $e ) {
     echo "$dberror1";
     //echo "message: " . $e->message;   // Not used for live production site.
     exit;
}

// Try to Set the active MySQL databaseand catch any failure with a controlled error message.
try {

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die ("$dberror2");

} catch (Exception $e ) {
     echo "$dberror2";
     //echo "message: " . $e->message;   // Not used for live production site.
     exit;

     // We want to stop supressing automated warnings after the database connection is completed.
     mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
   $run = mysqli_query($conn["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
```

should be

```
   $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Thank you so much your solution was a perfect fix! This is a big help to me because this same issue occurs in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

If you're migrating to mysqli, you should really read [these](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) at least.

The proper way to use a mysqli connection:

```php
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " id = " . $row['id'] . "\n";
    }
?>
```

you should also consider utilizing mysqli's prepared statements

Comment: Mario, thank you for the link to those docs. I have been lookup up old sql statements at php.net and then clicking the link where it says these are deprecated and following the link to the new mysqli functions. Then of course trying to learn them. Thank you for the code sample on the db connection. I had some concern though how this can echo the name of the db user upon an error and I am not sure if that is helpful?

Comment: This was just a very simple example. To echo the dbuser you're of course welcome to save the values in a variable and use that to call `new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database)`